# Case-insensitive ls sorting in Mac OSX

Tags: macos, mac, terminal

How can I make the `ls` command in Max OS X Lion sort files and directories similar to how Ubuntu Linux does (case-insensitive, directories NOT on top, dot files NOT on top)?  Ideally I'd like to do this without piping output to another command such as sort.

For example, I want to see:

```
foo
Foobar
MyStuff/
.stuff/
test.txt
```

instead of:

```
.stuff
Foobar
MyStuff/
foo
test.txt
```

In Linux, `ls` sort order is controlled by the system's locale, specifically `LC_COLLATE`.  When `LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8`, ls will sort items like I want.  When `LC_COLLATE=C`, `ls` will sort similar to OS X.

`LC_COLLATE` is set to `en_US.UTF-8` in OS X, but `ls` still sorts the old `POSIX` way.  Does anyone know how I can make this behave more like Linux?

Comment: If it helps: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/22304/8546 observes that HFS Plus is usually configured to be *case insensitive* but *case preserving*.

Comment: Note for Googlers: macOS `sort` and `ls` also respects LC_COLLATE, but the LC_COLLATE definition for locales like `en_US.UTF-8` is just a symlink that makes it behave like C locale. See [mike's answer below](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/140262/61160) for more details.

Answer (score 20):

It might not be possible:

> Taking a look at the [source code for ls](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/file_cmds/file_cmds-202.2/ls/), it uses strcoll to sort
>   the filenames, and so should respect LC_COLLATE.
>
> Some postings online suggest that the locales in BSD (and Darwin/OS X)
>   are somewhat broken compared to those in Linux. I wrote a quick
>   sorting program of my own which explicitly set it's locale and tested
>   it using both the en_US.UTF-8 and C locales on my machine (Mac OS
>   10.6.3) and a university machine (Linux, FC11?). While sorting works as expected on the linux machine, ("a B c" vs "B a c"), the mac always
>   sorts them as "B a c".

Source: http://ask.metafilter.com/130292/CaseInsensitive-LS-on-Mac-OS-X

#### **ORIGINAL ANSWER**

This command does not sort dot files, but shows additional directory listings

```
ls -f1
```

I got close to this:

```
.
..
.stuff
foo
Foobar
MyStuff
test.txt
```

Comment: Interesting that "disabling sort" with the -f option actually seems to sort it as expected. I assume this is the filesystem/HFS+ sorting entries with a more "natural" collation.

Comment: Recent Googlers note: `ls` and `sort` do indeed respect LC_COLLATE, but the definitions for LC_COLLATE are different in BSD/macOS compared to Linux. See the [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/140262/61160), which currently has many fewer votes.

Answer (score 6):

### Update as of Aug 1, 2021:

```sh
ls -alFG
```

Explanations:

```
-a      Include directory entries whose names begin with a dot (.).
-l      (The lowercase letter ``ell''.)  List in long format.  (See below.)  A total sum for all the file sizes is output on a line before the long
        listing.
-F      Display a slash (`/') immediately after each pathname that is a directory, an asterisk (`*') after each that is executable, an at sign (`@')
        after each symbolic link, an equals sign (`=') after each socket, a percent sign (`%') after each whiteout, and a vertical bar (`|') after
        each that is a FIFO.
-G      Enable colorized output.  This option is equivalent to defining CLICOLOR in the environment.  (See below.)
```

### Old:

I know this has been answered but this work best for me:

```sh
ls -f1 -alFG
```

It lists all details and sorts them by ignoring case.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with macOS 11.4 anymore (I get a truly unsorted listing probably reflecting the order in the filesystem).

Comment: @cbrnr Why downvote? I wrote this answer 7+ years ago. If you have a suggestion, suggest it.

Comment: I downvoted because your answer doesn't work anymore on macOS 11.4. However, the title specifically mentions OS X Lion, so I removed my downvote because it might still work there. The best solution on 11.4 seems to be `coreutils` and `gls`.

Answer (score 5):

This has been bugging me for awhile now, and I finally got it sorted (heh). After trying a bunch of suggestions that didn't work, here's what did.

If you're willing to install MacPorts (or Homebrew, or Fink), the GNU version of ls does exactly what you want. I use MacPorts, myself, so that's the approach I'll explain:

1. Download and install MacPorts:

   http://www.macports.org
2. Install the GNU Coreutils package:

   `sudo port install coreutils`
3. You should now have GNU ls: `gls`. Try it in a directory that contains items that start with both uppercase and lowercase letters:

   `gls -U`

   (The `-U` option actually means "unsorted", but on OS X that has the desired effect of making it case insensitive.)
4. Add this alias in your `.bash_profile` so the regular `ls` will work the way you want it to (I like the color output, but you can omit that if you want; you only need the `-U`):

   `alias ls='gls -U --color'`

Note that the `-U` option probably won't work on other platforms. In OS X, it always seems to do the right thing (maybe because HFS+ is effectively case-insensitive -- "case-aware", technically), but if you try it on a Linux box, the results will most likely just not be sorted at all.

Comment: 3. does not seem to have the desired side-effect anymore (-U option) under macOS >= 10.13 due to the new APFS.

Comment: Yep…doesn't look like there's any way to do this with APFS.

Comment: Confirm does work on 10.12 though. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Adding to  [Mike's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/140262/61160), I've taken it a bit further and found a way to define your own collation rules.

The locale definitions are located in /usr/share/locale/. Each folder is a locale and has a file (or a link) LC_COLLATE, which defines which symbols are "same" (for example, that U, u and ü should be considered the same when ordering). You can duplicate a directory and this will create a new locale definition:

```
$ sudo cp -R en_GB.UTF-8/ en_GB.UTF-8-CI/
```

Now you'll have a new locale called 'en_GB.UTF-8-CI' ('CI' for case-insensitive) and you can use LC_COLLATE from there.

Now, to change LC_COLLATE in the new locale you can download the locale sources from
http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/adv_cmds/adv_cmds-119/usr-share-locale.tproj/colldef/, edit the one that's closest to what you want and run

```
$ colldef < <new collation file>
$ sudo cp LC_COLLATE /usr/share/locale/en_GB.UTF-8-CI/
```

and now when you run

```
$ LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8-CI ls
```

you will have sorting according to *your* rules.

Yes, this is what it takes to make 'ls' sort case-insensitive.

Comment: perhaps consider using `/usr/local/share/locale` for your custom definition, which `man setlocale` indicates is also respected, and by default seems to only contain LC_MESSAGES for various locales.

Comment: @mmmmmm could you fix your edit -- you introduced a grammar problem

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround you can use a function and an alias:

```
function lssorted() { /bin/ls "$@" | sort -f ;}
alias ls='lssorted'
```

This produces a case insensitively sorted output for the standard ls command.

Comment: I have to note: this will fail if for example -l is used. Then ls produces another line "total X" at the beginning, which will also be sorted.

Answer (score 2):

ls is sorting according to LC_COLLATE, it's just that most all of the LC_COLLATE files are set to do case sensitive sorting.
http://collation-charts.org/fbsd54/

There are two that are set for case insensitive sorting:
cs_CZ.ISO8859-2 and et_EE.ISO8859-15
et_EE.ISO8859.15 doesn't sort "Z" the way english speakers would want.
cs.CZ.ISO8859-15 does a good job with the alphabet, I just wish it would sort "~" before alphabetic characters.

My solution is:
LC_COLLATE=cs_CZ.ISO8859-2 /bin/ls -FG

I wonder if a custom LC_COLLATE file could be made to handle "." the way you want and "~" the way I want.

Comment: indeed, if you look in `/usr/share/locale`, many LC_COLLATE files (e.g. en_US.UTF-8) are a symlink to la_LN.US-ASCII, which sorts uppercase before lowercase. cs_CZ.ISO8859-2 has its own LC_COLLATE file.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by [Mike's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/140262/61160), I added the following to /etc/bashrc, and it works beautifully in Mojave. It lists hidden files at the end, but that doesn't bother me.

```
export LC_COLLATE="cs_CZ.ISO8859-2"; alias ls='ls -AlhF'
```

You can see the new configuration by running the locale command. To revert, just remove the line from /etc/bashrc and log back into terminal.

```
$ locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="cs_CZ.ISO8859-2"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Note that neither ls -f1 nor ls -f worked for me in Mojave. I ended up with a truly unsorted list. Only the solution I have provided worked for me in Mojave.

UPDATE: Per user1561489's suggestion in comments, I had success with the following more efficient line placed in the /etc/bashrc file.

```
alias ls="LC_COLLATE=cs_CZ.ISO8859-2 ls -AlhF"
```

Comment: The best answer, but the example given does too much. It should be trimmed down to: put the following line into your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`: `alias ls="LC_COLLATE=cs_CZ.ISO8859-2 ls"`

Comment: @user1561489, I tried your suggestion, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: I just tried it again and it works for me in Catalina. Try make a temp directory and put two files in it: `README` and `dontreadme`. Normally `ls` will show `README` first. if I enter `alias ls="LC_COLLATE=cs_CZ.ISO8859-2 ls"` on the prompt and do `ls` again it will list `dontreadme` first

Comment: You're right. Worked in Mojave. I put the following in /etc/bashrc: alias ls="LC_COLLATE=cs_CZ.ISO8859-2 ls -AlhF". Added your suggestion as an update to my post, @user1561489.

Comment: might want to alias the sort command in the same way, depending on what your goals are

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
ls -f
```

works for me.

-f officially switches off any sorting, but it looks like then the original HFS sort shines through, which is exactly a case-insensitive sort.

I guess, it actually depends on whether you have your HD formated case-sensitive or not, but as case-INsensitive HFS format is the default for Mac OS X system disks, this should work for the majority of users.

Comment: This is definitely the right answer. The only issue with it is that it implicitly turns on -a as well, and there's no way to turn that off, which will show you files/folders beginning with a period, including . and .. .

Comment: The other problem (now) is that this doesn't seem to work anymore under macOS >= 10.13 due to the new APFS.

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
$ type ls
```

You'll probably find that your `ls` command is aliased.

Comment: On linux: `ls is /bin/ls`.  On OS X: `ls is hashed (/bin/ls)`.  Either way, even if I call `/bin/ls` directly it still doesn't sort according to LC_COLLATE.

Comment: That's surprising, I would have wagered that your `ls` command was aliased to include `--group-directories-first`. It may still be done somewhere else, just not an alias.

Answer (score 0):

If you are mainly concerned with the sort order of the dot files, you can sort *by extension*: Use the `ls` command from the [GNU Fileutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/fileutils/) with the option `--sort=extension`.  (You can install the GNU Fileutils e.g. through macports.)