# how to get ls to list files in case-insensitive order?

Tags: bash, command-line, unix, emacs, zsh

How do I get the `ls` shell command to list my files in:

1. case-insensitive order
2. with the directories at the top?

The reason I ask is: I want Aquamacs Emacs `dired` to list my files and directories this way. Emacs queries `ls` when displaying `dired`.

Which means I don't think piping using a command like 
     `ls -whatever | sort -f`
will work. (Or will it? Can I do something fancy with aliases?)

I'm using zsh at the moment, but I'm not sure that matters for Emacs.

Similar questions have been asked [here before](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34054/case-insensitive-ls-sorting-in-mac-osx) and [in other forums](http://ask.metafilter.com/130292/CaseInsensitive-LS-on-Mac-OS-X), but never resolved.

So, is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Emacs mode hooks to the rescue! Taken from [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredSortDirectoriesFirst):

```
(defun mydired-sort ()
  "Sort dired listings with directories first."
  (save-excursion
    (let (buffer-read-only)
      (forward-line 2) ;; beyond dir. header 
      (sort-regexp-fields t "^.*$" "[ ]*." (point) (point-max)))
    (set-buffer-modified-p nil)))

(defadvice dired-readin
  (after dired-after-updating-hook first () activate)
  "Sort dired listings with directories first before adding marks."
  (mydired-sort))
```

Comment: Amazing, that worked! Anyone have any thoughts on case-insensitivity?

Comment: The above works, but it appears to have broken `dired-details`, which causes `dired` to display files this way: `filename.org` instead of this way:`-rw-r--r--@    1 peter  peter     4000 Oct  5 18:21 filename.org`. Is there a way to make them play nicely together?

Comment: I don't have `dired-details` here, you may need to adjust the second regexp in `sort-regexp-fields`. For case-insensitive sorting, setting `sort-fold-case` to `non-nil` *should* do the trick.

Comment: I'm a newbie. Can you tell me how to set `sort-fold-case` (I don't find it as a variable when I do `C-h v`). And can you suggest syntax for how I might adjust the second regexp in `sort-regexp-fields` so I can play with it? Thank you.

Comment: I'll give it a shot on the weekend.

Comment: Update: if I hit `G` (Refresh), dired-details successfully omits the extraneous information. Any way to get it to do this automatically when I navigate to a directory?