# Sorting text with diacritics on OS X gives wrong results

Tags: macos, internationalization

Using postgresql I've noticed strange ordering issues. While investigating further, I've found a very informative [post](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4B4E845F.80906@postnewspapers.com.au). I've inspected further and it is true that LC_LOCALE files are the same for sl_SI.UTF-8, de_DE.UTF-8 and en_US.UTF-8 locales (and probably all others as well!).

A simple test-case on OSX: create a file named `de` with contents:

```
u
ü
ö
a
b
c
f
g
x
```

and from the Terminal, run `LANG="de_DE.UTF-8" LC_ALL="de_DE.UTF-8" sort de`. The output is:

```
a
b
c
f
g
u
x
ö
ü
```

where expected output (for instance, if I run this on Ubuntu linux) is:

```
a
b
c
f
g
ö
u
ü
x
```

My system has local files for those languages and I see [differences](http://pastebin.com/crg6h2dv) between en_US.UTF-8 and de_DE.UTF-8, just not in LC_COLLATE. Is there some reason OS X does not use LC_COLLATE settings? A related question: [Case-insensitive ls sorting in Mac OSX](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34054/case-insensitive-ls-sorting-in-mac-osx)

Comment: Any luck solving this? I have the same problem!

Comment: @Proghero No, unfortunately not. OS X is just for development, so not a deal breaker, but strange nontheless.