# case insensitive `ls` for Catalina / APFS?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, zsh

I am trying to find a way to get either the stock macOS `ls` or (more likely) the GNU `ls` a.k.a. `gls` to show my files & folders in ***case insensitive*** order.

All of my efforts have resulted in lowercase letters being sorted *after* the uppercase letters.

## ⚠️ There are lots of *outdated* answers which *no longer work!*

This same question was asked on this forum in [October 2011](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34054/case-insensitive-ls-sorting-in-mac-osx) (and in [August 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413646/making-the-ls-command-sort-a-before-b-vs-a-b-a-b) on Stack Overflow), but those answers no longer work on macOS in 2020.

### What I've tried that does not work:

1. `LC_COLLATE` does not seem to have any effect. I have tried these variations:

   ```
   LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"

   LC_COLLATE="cs_CZ.ISO8859-2"

   LANG="en_US.UTF-8" LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
   ```

   There was no noticeable effect at all.
2. Apparently `ls -f` or `gls -U` used to work for HFS+, although the output was supposed to be "unsorted", but apparently somehow in HFS+ "unsorted" was *¿accidentally? ¿coincidentally?* case-insensitive? I guess? Whatever the reason, it no longer works, presumably because we’re using APFS now.
3. **”Just pipe it through `sort -f`!”** was never *really* an answer, but someone always seems to suggest it anyway. I want to be able to use all of the other features of `ls`/`gls` including color and `-C` which doesn’t work if we have to pipe through another command.

---

Is there some hidden method out there that I might have missed? Or does this functionality is actually not possible? The latter would seem extremely odd to me, but stranger things have happened, I guess.

**P.S.** - I use `zsh` as my default shell anyway, so if there’s a way to replicate this with `zsh` that would be OK too.

Answer (score 3):

If done properly the LC_COLLATE method works:

Example:

```
user@host ~ % export LC_COLLATE="cs_CZ.ISO8859-2" && ls -la
total 56
-rw-r--r--   1 user      staff      0 Mar  1 20:39 bin
drwx------+  4 user      staff    128 Jan 30 10:51 Desktop
drwx------+  3 user      staff     96 Oct  9 04:40 Documents
drwx------+  4 user      staff    128 Jan  4 21:11 Downloads
drwx------+ 61 user      staff   1952 Nov  2 10:29 Library
drwx------+  4 user      staff    128 Oct  9 18:17 Movies
drwx------+  3 user      staff     96 Oct  9 04:40 Music
drwx------+  5 user      staff    160 Oct 10 03:22 Pictures
drwxr-xr-x+  4 user      staff    128 Oct  9 04:40 Public
drwxr-xr-x+ 18 user      staff    576 Mar  1 20:40 .
-r--------   1 user      staff      7 Oct  9 04:43 .CFUserTextEncoding
drwxr-xr-x   3 user      staff     96 Oct 10 17:50 .config
-rw-r--r--@  1 user      staff  14340 Dec 26 22:14 .DS_Store
drwx------   6 user      staff    192 Nov 22 11:40 .ssh
drwx------   2 user      staff     64 Mar  1 20:35 .Trash
-rw-r--r--@  1 user      staff   2620 Nov 15 02:44 .zprofile
-rw-------@  1 user      staff   1544 Mar  1 20:40 .zsh_history
drwxr-xr-x   5 root      admin    160 Sep 29 22:22 ..
```

So simply add `export LC_COLLATE="cs_CZ.ISO8859-2"` to your .zprofile/.zshrc/... and restart Terminal.

If you use this locale you might experience some irregularities in shell outputs/history files etc.

Here (using mixed us_en/de_de locales im macOS) I got some irregular entries in the command history (i.e. .zsh_history) after entering German umlauts.

---

Probably the best idea then: create a new custom LC_COLLATE file.

Comment: Curious. I did not get that result when I tried this in `zsh` but if I try it on an account without my .zshenv/.zshrc then it works. Will have to ask the `zsh` folks for some help figuring out why it's not working for me. Must be a conflict in one of my other settings. Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest an alias for ls instead of setting LC_COLLATE globally.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that I wouldn't change the global `LC_COLLATE`.
Just use it locally in your alias:

`alias ls="LC_COLLATE=cs_CZ.ISO8859-2 /bin/ls"`

Watch out for the undesirable effect of this particular LOCALE. Files that start with "ch", "CH", or "Ch" will be sorted between files that
start with "H" and "i".

I would like to create my own custom file, I'm going to try out this:
https://gist.github.com/shaunsauve/56c30ad45d1261e7164e1b32316ef7c1

Answer (score 0):

You can get there by using `LC_COLLATE="cs_CZ.ISO8859-2"`.

But watch out for this curiosity regarding the differences between the stock 'ls' command on `macOS 10.15.4` box, and `gls` (`GNU ls` from `coreutils` via `brew`):

```
λ export LC_COLLATE="cs_CZ.ISO8859-2" && ls -la

-rw-r--r--    1 storm  staff   695  8 nov 06:35 argv.json
drwxr-xr-x   61 storm  staff  1952 22 apr 19:02 extensions
drwxr-xr-x    4 storm  staff   128  8 nov 06:35 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 154 storm  staff  4928 23 apr 10:43 ..
```

```
λ export LC_COLLATE="cs_CZ.ISO8859g-2" && gls -la

total 4
drwxr-xr-x    4 storm staff  128 Nov  8 06:35 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 154 storm staff 4928 Apr 23 10:43 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 storm staff  695 Nov  8 06:35 argv.json
drwxr-xr-x   61 storm staff 1952 Apr 22 19:02 extensions
```

Not sure how `ls` and `gls` end up sorting `.` and `..` differently based on the same locale lexer info, but it does.